# can't call .catch on a function unless it's wrapped?

Tags: asynchronous, promise

I have an async function such as this

```
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  const posts = await Post.find({});
  res.render("index", { title: "Homepage", posts });
});
```

and I can wrap it in a function that handles its catch

```
function catchAsync(fn) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    fn(req, res, next).catch((e) => next(e));
  };
}
```

so it looks like this

```
router.get(
  "/",
  catchAsync(async function (req, res, next) {
    const posts = await Post.find({});
    res.render("index", { title: "Homepage", posts });
  })
);
```

but my doubt, and the reason for this post, is why can't I call .catch directly on the async function, like so?

```
router.get(
  "/",
  async function (req, res, next) {
    const posts = await Post.find({});
    res.render("index", { title: "Homepage", posts });
  }.catch((e) => next(e))
);
```

I understand I **can** do this however

```
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  my_callback(req, res, next).catch((e) => {
    next(e);
  });
});

let my_callback = async function (req, res, next) {
  const posts = await Post.find({});
  res.render("index", { title: "Homepage", posts });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling `.catch` on a `Promise` ***returned*** by ***calling*** `my_callback` function

```js
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  my_callback(req, res, next).catch((e) => {
    next(e);
  });
});
```

Here you are trying to access `.catch` on a function ***definition*** which is syntactically wrong in JavaScript

```
router.get(
  "/",
  async function (req, res, next) {
    const posts = await Post.find({});
    res.render("index", { title: "Homepage", posts });
  }.catch((e) => next(e))
);
```

If you want to include `catch` with the function definition then you can use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

More reading about promises - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise